# What do `%ifdef` and `%defstr` do in assembly (in layman's terms)?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm reading through [some assembly source code](https://github.com/redox-os/bootloader/blob/master/x86_64/disk.asm) just for learning purposes (I like to learn by figuring out code).

I came across the following lines:

```
%ifdef KERNEL
    kernel_file:
      %defstr KERNEL_STR %[KERNEL]
      incbin KERNEL_STR
    .end:
    align 512, db 0
%else
    align BLOCK_SIZE, db 0
    %ifdef FILESYSTEM
        filesystem:
            %defstr FILESYSTEM_STR %[FILESYSTEM]
            incbin FILESYSTEM_STR
        .end:
        align BLOCK_SIZE, db 0
    %else
        filesystem:
    %endif
%endif
```

I know what `%include` does and I can tell that `%ifdef` is an **if statement**.

I'm completely lost with `%defstr`. I've only found an explanation on [this](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html) website and got even more confused.

Can someone give me a VERY BASIC explanation as to what it does?

Comment: What assembler is this?

Comment: @fuz- I'm assuming NASM

Comment: That construct basically adds quotes. If `KERNEL` is `foo` then `KERNEL_STR` will be `"foo"`. The `incbin` directive requires the quotes, but for whatever reason `KERNEL` has not been defined with them included.

Comment: @Jester - Ahhh that makes a lot of sense. I was assuming "define string" then got lost there, but your explanation cleared things up. Thanks :)